# Is appengine Python datastore query much (>3x) slower than Java?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've been investigating the appengine to see if I can use it for a
project and while trying to choose between Python and Java, I ran into
a surprising difference in datastore query performance: medium to
large datastore queries are more than 3 times slower in Python than in
Java.

My question is: is this performance difference for datastore queries
(Python 3x slower than Java) normal, or am I doing something wrong in
my Python code that's messing with the numbers?

My entity looks like this:

## Person

firstname (length 8)
lastname (length 8)
address (20)
city (10)
state (2)
zip (5)

I populate the datastore with 2000 Person records, with each field
exactly the length noted here, all filled with random data and with no
fields indexed (just so the inserts go faster).

I then query 1k Person records from Python (no filters, no ordering):

```
q = datastore.Query("Person")
objects = list(q.Get(1000))
```

And 1k Person records from Java (likewise no filters, no ordering):

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("Person");
PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
// Force the query to run and return objects so we can be sure
// we've timed a full query.
List<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>(pq.asList(withLimit(1000)));
```

With this code, the Java code returns results in ~200ms; the Python
code takes much longer, averaging >700ms. Both apps are on the same
app id (with different versions), so they use the same datastore and should
be on a level playing field.

All my code is available here, in case I've missed any details:

http://github.com/greensnark/appenginedatastoretest

Comment: Have you used appstats to determine just where the time is being spent? Joshua is most likely correct here, because the datastore backend is the same for all runtimes, but appstats will tell you for sure.

Comment: Appstats reports times like this "datastore_v3.RunQuery real=122ms api=9179ms" for Java and times like "datastore_v3.RunQuery real=377ms api=9179ms" for Python. I'm guessing this means that the RPC cost is the same for both, but the Python code spends more time on the operation anyway. The real elapsed time for the Java datastore query (averaged) is ~200ms and ~780ms for Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be an expected difference between Python and Java. Most likely you aren't seeing differences in the amount of time to make the query, but the amount of time it takes to parse the result and fill the receiving data structure.

You can test this by comparing the time it takes to query a single record. Remember that you'll need to test several times and average the total to get a true benchmark to account for possible fluctuations in latency on the backend.

In general, you can expect a <strike>compiled</strike> *statically typed language* like Java or Scala to always be faster than an <strike>interpreted language</strike> *dynamically typed language* like Ruby or Python.

Comment: Both Python and Java are compiled to byte codes which are interpreted on a virtual machine. Python and Ruby are not equivalent in that regard.

Comment: You're right, it looks like all the slowdown for the Python code happens when decoding the returned protocol buffer data into Entity objects in the SDK's datastore.py. Small datastore queries (10 objects) show no perceptible performance difference between Java and Python.

Comment: @Joshua, the generalization you make at the end of your post is not quite accurate in general, as adam pointed out. In addition, one needs to consider the specific context of app engine, where java apps with low traffic have to pay the startup cost of initializing the entire jvm quite frequently.

Comment: From the Python documentation "Python is an interpreted language, as opposed to a compiled one, though the distinction can be blurry because of the presence of the bytecode compiler. This means that source files can be run directly without explicitly creating an executable which is then run."

Comment: This article explains the differences well. http://www.razorvine.net/python/PythonComparedToJava

Comment: really we should talk about specific runtimes being interpreters or compilers rather than languages.  most languages can be run in more than one manner, which blurs the compiled/interpreted issue even further.